# How do I deal with finding a partition for a specific epsilon?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, solution-verification

Hello everyone my name is Alice and I am new to this website.

Here is the problem I am working on:

> Let the function f : [0, 1] → R be defined by f(x) = x. Find a
> partition P of the interval [0, 1] such that the upper sum U(f, P) and
> the lower sum L(f, P) satisfy the inequality
>
> $U\left(f,\:P\right)-L\left(f,P\right)\:<\:\frac{1}{3}$
>
> and I have to show that how I compute or estimate $U(f, P) − L(f, P)$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $P = \{x_0, ..., x_i\}$ be any partition of $[0, 1]$

Using the definition of upper sum and lower sum:

$
L(f,P) = \sum^n_{i=1}m_i(x_i - x_{i-1})$ here $m_i$ is the infimum of $f(x)$ in the interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i].$ And same thing for upper sum but we have supremum instead.

Since we have $f(x) = x$, which is a increasing function, so the infimum of the interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ will always be $x_{i-1}$ and the supremum of the interval will always be $x_i$

so rewriting the definition of the upper sum and the lower sum, I get:

$ L(f,P) = \sum^n_{i=1} x_{i-1}(x_i - x_{i-1})$

$ U(f,P) = \sum^n_{i=1} x_i(x_i - x_{i-1})$

$ U(f,P) - L(f,P) = \sum^n_{i=1} x_i(x_i - x_{i-1}) - \sum^n_{i=1} x_{i-1}(x_i - x_{i-1})$
here I am allowed to factor out the summation symbol right?

$= \sum^n_{i=1}(x_i - x_{i-1})(x_i - x_{i-1})$

This is where I am stuck, I need to show that this expression is less than $\frac{1}{3}$ but I am not sure how to create an inequality. Maybe I need this: $ 0 < x_0 < x_i < x_n = 1$ ? I am not sure.

It will be really nice if someone can help me tq- Alice

Comment: You get to pick the partition, you don't have to take an arbitrary one.  For example, try the partition 0, .5,1  and see what your upper sum and lower sum look like there.  If that's not fine enough,  try a finer partition

Comment: @Alan Hi Alan, thanks for the comment, so this is pretty much trial and error?

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion of @Alan, let $n>0$ be an integer, and consider the partition $P=(x_i)_{i=0,1,\ldots,n}$ with $x_i :=i/n$, that is

$$ P:=\left(0,\frac1n,\frac2n,\ldots,\frac{n-1}n,1\right). $$

Then:

$$ U(f,P)-L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1{n^2} = \frac1n<\epsilon $$

for $n>\frac1\epsilon$.

If, as in your question, $\epsilon=1/3$, we obtain $n>3$, and for example

$$ P=\left(0,\frac14,\frac24,\frac34,1\right) $$

works.

Comment: Hi sir thank you for your answer! I have some questions. How do you get $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1{n^2}$?

Comment: @AliceRathbone - From the definition $\;x_i=\frac in$, we have $\;x_i-x_{i-1}=\frac in-\frac{i-1}n=\frac{i-(i-1)}n=\frac 1n$, so $\;(x_i-x_{i-1})^2=\left(\frac1n\right)^2=\frac1{n^2}$ for all $i$. It follows: $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1})^2 = n\cdot\frac1{n^2}=\frac1n$.